# Record exist in one DB2 table but not in another table

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 DB2 tables. I want to find out records that are in table A is not Table B with the following condition 
I wrote this query and it is not working

```
      SELECT A.CL_BATCH_DEPT,                                         
      A.CL_TRANS_CODE, A.CL_CUR_DOC_NO                                
      FROM DBPA60AC.TB_ACCOUNT_EVENT A                              
      LEFT JOIN DBPA60AC.TB_DOCUMENT B  ON A.CL_CUR_DOC_NO  = B.CL_DOCNO                       
      WHERE A.CL_BATCH_DEPT = 'R07' AND  A.CL_TRANS_CODE = '210'
      AND A.CL_CUR_DOC_NO  = "PI%" AND                         
      B CL_DOCNO IS NULL
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  What conditions do you want?  How is anyone else supposed to figure out the conditions based on a not-working query?

Comment: It is giving sql error

Comment: What's the exact error message? Multiple errors. String constants in Db2 must be enclosed in single quotes, not double ones. Remove space in `B CL_DOCNO`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM DBPA60AC.TB_ACCOUNT_EVENT e LEFT JOIN 
     DBPA60AC.TB_DOCUMENT d
     ON e.CL_CUR_DOC_NO = d.CL_DOCNO
WHERE e.CL_BATCH_DEPT = 'R07' AND
      e.CL_TRANS_CODE = '210' AND
      e.CL_CUR_DOC_NO LIKE 'PI%' AND
      d.CL_DOCNO IS NULL;
```

That is, the comparison to `PI%` suggests that you really want `LIKE`.

Note that I also changed the aliases so they are meaningful.